# Logic Behind Social Login

Tags: authentication, logic, facebook-login, google-signin

I have created a nice little login script for my website that lets users login with **Facebook** or **Google** at the moment.

What I am trying to do is **set some checks to make sure that duplicates do not appear** in the database.

Here are some scenarios I have covered :

- Login with Google/Facebook account and I have already registered this account, *This will log the user straight in as they have already linked this account.*
- User has *already registered with Google* account, yet clicks **Facebook** because they cannot remember which account they used. This will alert the user that the email address returned from *Facebook* has already been registered with a *Google* account. This will enable them to click on *Facebook to Login* **??? NOT SURE ON THIS LOGIC AT THE MOMENT ???**
- User clicks on *Google/Facebook* to login, yet the email address returned is a user that went through the **manual registration**. This will alert the user that the social account they are trying to login with **will require a password**.

What I am thinking of doing is allowing users to *LINK ACCOUNT* so that the alerting process does not happen because I can link my facebook account to my google account through my website, and vice versa etc etc.

**What I am asking :**

Are there any other checks I may be missing? **Is this logic** sound? Is there anything I am doing which makes you question the login process??

Basically asking **logic advice** on this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well congratulations! You're almost on the right track. Let's breakdown your situation here.

**Ideal Situation**

```
1. Registered on your site
2. Log in with Google
3. Log in with Facebook
```

Now, let's take the common denominator here, I mean the primary key. I am guessing in your case it should be the email address.

**Actual Process Flow**

```
1. User registers. You save the email address
```

Or,

```
2. User registers with Google/Facebook and you save the email address.
```

**Login Procedure**

```
1. You receive the email address either from direct login/facebook/google.
2. You match it against your table
3. On positive match, you link this social login to an existing account
```

If,

```
4. It is not a positive match then you accept whatever data you receive and then forward
   and then pass on to the registration page.
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you want to know anything else.

Cheers!

Comment: This is the solution to the question as asked, but I would warn that email as a primary key across SSOs is a risky direction and inappropriate for sites where the user can enter anything personal. (Examples: if you forget to check google's email_verified, all accounts are now at risk. If a google SSO user never uses fb, but the address had a previous owner who did.. oops.) Indicating a new user may have another account is a lesser evil, but just clearly indicating that they are entering a new account creation that can be aborted is safer still.

Comment: Conceded! You are right. Now, with this question comes a very important scenario, i.e. business logic. We make CRM's for a living. In every case, each customer has a different primary key. Sometimes for an insurance company it is a phone number, for a dating service, it is an email address, for someone else it might be an application ID. So, you have to ensure that you handle the primary key at your end. What I would have done is, gone ahead with SSO and then show probable matches and then let the user pick one. Initially after an OAuth registration have the user fill some extra info as well.

Comment: I think as the only person willing to answer, and someone who seems to be going along the right lines you deserve the bounty on this one. I may not agree **100%** with your procedure - but it isn't far off what I required.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah to be honest, the procedure is definitely not one-for-all situations thing... I usually adapt to the situation at hand. :)

Comment: I thing you miss one case like if any user register in facebook using facebook mobile app that case email address not register on facebook profile and user login using mobile no and when without email he login from facebook on his website then email id not come from facebook login then how you handel that case ?